# How do I convert a JSON to an object literal?

Tags: javascript, json, object-literal

I get data from a source in the form of a JSON. Let's say the JSON looks like this

```
var data = [
   {"city" : "Bangalore", "population" : "2460832"}
]
```

I'd be passing this data object into a kendo grid and I'll be using its out-of-the-box features to format numbers. So, I need the same JSON as an object literal that looks like this

```
var data = [{city : "Bangalore", population: 2460832}]
```

Are there any libraries, functions or simple ways to achieve this?

Comment: if it has a well known structure, just use `parseInt` for that property!

Comment: That "JSON" is not JSON. It's JavaScript. The only object literals you have are the same in both versions of the code. The only differences are that you have replaced a string literal with a number literal.

Comment: But the end result should like an object literal so that I can reuse it anywhere I want. I don't want to apply parseInt repeatedly.

Comment: "Object literal" is irrelevant. You want to have your *data structure* in a certain way. The problem is that in one data structure the *values* are strings, whereas you need them to be *numbers*. It doesn't matter for the type of the value whether it's expressed as an "object literal" or what. The type of the value is wrong, period. You need to convert it, period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [iterate over the `Object`s in the `Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and modify each `population` property, converting its value from a string to a number with [`parseInt()` or similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-in-javascript):

```
var data = [
    {"city" : "Bangalore", "population" : "2460832"}
];

data.forEach(function (entry) {
    entry.population = parseInt(entry.population, 10);
});

console.log(data[0].population);        // 2460832
console.log(typeof data[0].population); // 'number'
```

Comment: I applied this solution and it works fine. But I'm still uncomfortable with having to apply it every where I need it. I was hoping to find an out of the box solution where I can do this only once and then keep reusing the data. But thanks. I've got what I needed for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert JSON into an object literal by following this idea:

```
(function() { 

  var json = 
   [
    {
      "id": 101,
      "title": 'title 1'
    }, 
    {
      "id": 103,
      "title": 'title 3'
    },
    {
      "id": 104,
      "title": 'title 4'
    }
  ];

  var result = {};  

  for (var key in json) {
    var json_temp = {} 
    json_temp.title = json[key].title;
    result[json[key].id] = json_temp;
  }

  console.log(result);

})();
```

The output will be:

```
Object {
  101: Object {
     title: "title 1" 
  }
  102: Object {
     title: "title 2" 
  }
  103: Object {
     title: "title 3" 
  }
}
```